# Is it possible to automatically publish my project readme.md file to GitLabs pages?

Tags: gitlab, hugo

I'm new to, and currently using GitLab Pages and Hugo (v0.23 with theme by Beautiful Jekyll) for my website. I've just finished a small coding project which is up on GitLabs and has a project readme.md file.

I'd like to publish the project readme.md file to my webpage. Is there a way to ensure if I update the project readme.md file it will automatically update on my webpage post?

Currently my approach to publish my project readme.md file to my webpage is:

1. create project readme.md file in project repository
2. create post.md and save in website repository for my posts
3. copy project readme.md file contents to post.md (manual step)

I want to know if it's possible to:

1. create project readme.md file in project directory
2. create post.md in website repository
3. link content of project readme.md to post.md

Thus if I update readme.md file I will see new content automatically updated on post.md (and thus my website).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some research and the answer is in short no.

The readme.md files are stored separately from the post.md file. Therefore a manual copy-paste is required.

Though the readme.md file can be linked from the post.md file.